How to secure multiple third-level subdomains with one TLS/SSL certificate?
Question:
Is it possibile to have wildcard certificate for *.domain1.com and add one SAN for *.domain2.domain1.com which will cover all our partners?
More info:
I have an issue at organization. We are using external system with our own domain names for cooperation with partners. Structure there works like this:
Partnername.domain2.domain1.com and every partner has it's own space accessed via domain names maching his company name.
Up to 99 partners we were using certificate from LetsEncrypt provided by app owner. LetsEncrypt Has 100 Subject Alt Names limit
However now we have more than 100 partners and wanted to use our own certificate
We have checked few vendors and noone allows buying wildcard for second-level subdomains like *.domain2.domain1.com
If there is no way to have working SAN for *.domain2.domain1.com with cert issued for *.domain1.com is there any other way than mannualy adding SAN for every partner?
Couldn't find informarion if *.domain2.domain1.com SAN entry will work
